# Compiler differences with references

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I am compiled the following code.

```
#include <iostream> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a = 2; 
    int $b = a; 
    b = 3; 
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

When I compile it in Visual Studio 2012 it outputs 3 as expected. However, when I compile it in g++ 3.4.4 I receive the following error.

```
error: `b' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Why does the following compile in Visual Studio 2012 but not in g++?

Comment: Doesn't compile in my VS2012. Any particular reason you're using $b?

Comment: Are you really using a `$` in your code? That is not allowed.

Comment: `int $b = a;`? What's this?

Comment: In addition, why would this print "3" when a = 2? I don't think this is your actual code.

Comment: @juanchopanza It is allowed.

Comment: Why would you use the $ symbol in a question about c++ references, is what I find myself wondering. Sure, if line 5 said ***int &b = a;*** then the code would work just fine in either. But I'm entirely lost as to why you'd use the $ symbol instead of the & operator. Can you provide a link that details such usage?

Comment: Please don't edit in answers/notes about the question in the question; that would be more appropriate in a comment, such as this. At any rate, this question has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the title, I guess you were trying to do this:

```
int& b = a;
```

`&` is, as far as I know, the only standard to declare a reference.

Look @H2CO3 answer as to why this compile in VS.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the following compile in Visual Studio 2012

Because either VS is crap or you set it to C++/PHP mode.

> but not in g++?

Because `b` is not declared, only `$b`.

Comment: To their defense, it is documented that [a dollar sign is allowed in VC++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d.aspx).